# After deleting a video ,video gets deleted but my cursor returns same file path

Tags: video

```
public void delete_file_using_file_path(String filePath)
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
        if(deleted == true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,  filePath + " deleted sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

by this i am able to delete video file.

Answer (score 0):

The indexer takes a while to update the database. It will not remove the video immediately.